# Создание куков через HTTP

Tags: javascript, http, cookie

Как создать куки на `http`, скрипт срабатывает на `https`, как сделать для `http`?

```
var date = new Date(new Date().getTime() + (1*24*60*60*1000));
    document.cookie = name_cookie 
                       + "=true; path=/;secure=true; expires=" 
                       + date.toUTCString();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы же сами ставите `secure` флаг.
Если Вы имеете ввиду флаг `httpOnly`, то, разумеется, через JS этого не сделать.
Иначе потеряется весь смысл этой фичи.